# Slider like vimeo in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, slider

In my database I have 3 categories and each category has videos. What I want to do is, like [vimeo.com/watch](http://vimeo.com/watch), make a slider but each row has just 4 videos/images. I got confused so I didn't create algorithm for that. I'm using Bootstrap Carousel.

Short explanation:

```
category1
image1 image2 image3 image4 > (other images will appear when they click next)

category2
image1 image2 image3 image4 > (other images will appear when they click next)

category3
image1 image2 image3 image4 > (other images will appear when they click next)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to do something like that.

```
foreach (var c in categories)
{
    // append html for category image and name

    int i = 0;

    foreach (var v in c.Videos)
    {

        if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
        {
            // that means begin new row with 4 columnd
        }
        else
        {
            // append html for video or image or whatever you want to add ...
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exaclty what I wanted.